# I want to extract some columns in a table A that do not have an entry in table B. How can I achieve that in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I want to extract some columns in a table (A) that do not have an entry in table (B). How can I achieve that in Hive? I'm working on a query (below) but it's not working at the moment, please help.

Join Columns:  product_name in prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn to SFDC_PRODUCT_NAME in prd_raw_sf.sf_product_pcu_mapping

```
select *
FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn  
JOIN prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping ON prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn.account_name = prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping.sfdc_account_name
WHERE prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn.account_name not in (select * from prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `left join` antipattern comes to mind here:

```
select o.*
from prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn o
left prd_raw_sf.join sf_si_accounts_mapping m on o.account_name = m.sfdc_account_name
where m.sfdc_account_name is null
```

The query attempts to `join` each record in `sf_opportunity_dn` with `sf_si_accounts_mapping`, then the `where` clause filters on only records that *could not* be joined.

With an the following indexes, this should be an efficient solution:

```
prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn(account_name )
prd_raw_sf.join sf_si_accounts_mapping(sfdc_account_name)
```

Note: table aliases make the query shorter and easier to understand. I added them to your query, and I would recommend that you use them at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `not exists`.  A `join` doesn't seem necessary:

```
select o.*
from prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn o 
where not exists (select 1
                  from prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping a
                  where o.account_name = a.account_name
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Left join` and `Left semi join`

Left Join approach :

```
select a.*
FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn  as a
LEFT JOIN prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping as b 
      ON a.account_name = b.sfdc_account_name
WHERE b.sfdc_account_name is Null;
```

Left Semi join :

```
select a.*
    FROM prd_raw_sf.sf_opportunity_dn  as a
    LEFT SEMI JOIN prd_raw_sf.sf_si_accounts_mapping as b 
          ON a.account_name = b.sfdc_account_name
```

Performance wise left semi join is better as compared to left join because it only checks as soon as first matching record is found in second table and skips the remaining matches for particular keys